# WCF duplex communication

Tags: c#, wcf, tcp, broadcast, self-hosting

I need to re-write an existing client-server application.
The existing application communicate using socket, I have to convert it into WCF.

At server side I need to

- Monitor connected clients
- Validate client request
- Broadcast live data (comming from diff source).
- Listen to client and respond to it

At client end I need to

- Receive server broadcast and display it on UI.
- Display UI and take input from user
- Submit user data to server and display response

I have chosen tcp protocol on self hosting environment.

I need some immediate level references (link, tutorial, book)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this : [WCF on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms735119(VS.90).aspx)

I don't know if you can get it, but Microsoft book on WCF (course 6461A) is not bad.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this MSDN article, covers pretty much everything you need to know to build a duplex service in WCF:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163537.aspx